# How to Export data in Excel including images in php

Tags: php

i am exporting data from database (MySQL) in excel sheet. i also want to export images in Excel using PHP.if any demo link is available, please share it here

Comment: Please put the code what ever you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use one of the followig library to do that.

URLS:

```
https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

https://code.google.com/p/php-excel/
```

Comment: Technically, two of those are the same library: PHPExcel on codeplex is the same as PHPExcel in the PHPOffice repo on github

Comment: Actually, i'm trying to give more details about that PHPExcel library. So One can find code in first URL. 2nd URL is for full details about that library

Comment: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/wiki/User%20Documentation is a useful reference on github

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is **PHPExcel**.

Here are some [**examples**](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Home).

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved mine. Hope this helps!

```html
public function export_items_to_excel(){
   $items = $this->transaction->view_all_items();

   $output = '';

   $output .= "<table class='table' border='1'>
      <thead>
                   <th style='background-color:#c7c7c7;'>NAME</th>  
                   <th style='background-color:#c7c7c7;'>DESCRIPTION</th>      
                   <th style='background-color:#c7c7c7;'>QUANTITY</th>
                   <th style='background-color:#c7c7c7;'>WEIGHT (KG)</th>
                   <th style='background-color:#c7c7c7;'>HS CODE</th>
                   <th style='background-color:#c7c7c7;'>SERIAL NO.</th>
                   <th style='background-color:#c7c7c7;'>UNIT VALUE</th>
                   <th style='background-color:#c7c7c7;'>CURRENCY</th>
                   <th style='width:220px !important;background-color:#c7c7c7;'>PICTURE</th>
               </thead>
            <tbody>
      ";
  foreach($items as $item){ 
  $output .= "
    <tr>
     <td style='text-align:center;'>".$item->item_name."</td>
     <td style='text-align:center;'>".$item->item_description."</td>
     <td style='text-align:center;'>".$item->item_quantity."</td>
     <td style='text-align:center;'>".number_format($item->item_weight, 2)."</td>
     <td style='text-align:center;'>".$item->item_hs_code."</td>
     <td style='text-align:center;'>".$item->item_serial_number."</td>
     <td style='text-align:center;'>".number_format($item->item_unit_value, 2)."</td>
     <td style='text-align:center;'>".$item->item_currency."</td>
     <td style='text-align:center;width:220px !important;height:220px !important;'><img src='".base_url()."assets/uploads/".$item->item_picture."' style='width:200px !important;height:152px !important;'> </td>
    </tr>
     ";
        }
        $output .= "</tbody>
          </table>
         ";
        header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=items.xls");
        header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");
        echo $output;
  }
```